# What does "expected item, found let" mean?

Tags: rust

My code

```rust
pub struct MyStorage {
    name: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Storage for MyStorage {
    //let mut name: Vec<u8> = [0x11];
    fn get(&mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.name
    }
}

let my_storage = MyStorage { name = [0x11] };
```

returns the error

```
error: expected item, found keyword `let`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | let my_storage = MyStorage { name = [0x11] };
   | ^^^ expected item
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 12):

There's a number of issues with this code, but the error you are getting is because you are trying to *execute* code but not from within a function:

```rust
let my_storage = MyStorage { name = [0x11] };
```

You need to put that in something. Here, I've added it to `main`:

```rust
pub struct MyStorage {
    name: Vec<u8>,
}

impl MyStorage {
    fn get(self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.name
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_storage = MyStorage { name: vec![0x11] };
}
```

I also had to:

- fix the vector construction (`vec!`)
- remove the usage of a trait that doesn't exist (`Storage`)
- change the type of `self` in `get`
- change from `=` to `:`

With all that, the code compiles.

Comment: But then, how do I use that main function? I specifically was trying not to use main because I want to return name you see. Also, the trait reference DOES exist, I just didnt put it in the code. The trait is Storage and for the train, I implement method get then use my_storage to return a vector of bytes and run tests with it. Should I repost my question or edit it for you to have a look at the entire thing?

Comment: @Lexka It's generally a good idea to produce a [small example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. To that end, you should have tried to remove as much as you could before posting, but I think your question is OK to leave for now.

Comment: @Lexka Where would you like to return the name *to*? In my example, `name` is being removed from `MyStorage` and returned by `get` back to the `main` function. Do you mean printed to the console?

Comment: Hey Shepmaster. The function is simply meant to be used within an another function and return name, then I run an assert comparison test. If it works in main, it should work in any function, I am not looking to print anything for now. Anyways, would you have an idea how to produce a random vector of it with dynamic size at all (maybe fixed size to start). I looked about the net and can't quite find anything yet. So if you can help with this, smashing. And oh, thanks for your help ealrier, I will adapt your changes.

Comment: @Lexka that sounds like a good question to ask separately. Asking separate, well-worded questions helps future searchers find what they are looking for. Would *you* have looked at a question with this title to figure out how to make a random vector of dynamic size? ^_^